# Find frequency table without using dcast

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency, tidyverse

Given Data

```
> data
  Month Alpha
1   Jan     A
2   Jan     B
3   Jan     A
4   Feb     B
5 March     A
6 March     A
7 April     A
```

Required Output

[image]

Please provide solution without the use of dcast function either by using group_by() or spread() functions. Not been able to use the functions properly.

Comment: Consider to tell us why you don`t want to use `dcast`.

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: I have done it using dcast but want to try using the other method. Sticking to Tidyverse whereas dcast is using data.table.

Comment: Please read comments left on your posts. I advised you to use `dput` but you seem to have ignored the advice. Also please accept answers if they help. It's common courtesy!

Comment: Have you seen ??spread. In examples, you will find exactly your case.

Comment: With `dplyr` you can do something like `df %>%
 group_by(Month, Alpha) %>%
 mutate(count = n()) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 gather(var, val, -Month, -Alpha) %>%
 distinct() %>%
 spread(Alpha, val, fill = 0) %>%
 select(-var)`.

Comment: @tmfmnk A bit simpler seems `group_by(dat, Month, Alpha) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% spread(Alpha, n, fill = 0)`

Comment: @markus I was just going to add the same.

Comment: `data %>% count(Month, Alpha) %>% spread(Alpha, n, fill = 0L)`

Comment: @markus definitely a more elegant solution, good to know it.

Comment: @tmfmnk Yeah I was looking for this. Thankyou.  But if you could explain from the gather function I'd be grateful.

Comment: @tmfmnk But see alistaire's solution which is even nicer.

Comment: `table(data$Month, data$Alpha)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution:

```
with(df,table(Month,Alpha))


     Alpha
Month   A B
  April 1 0
  Feb   0 1
  Jan   2 1
  March 2 0
```

A `tidyverse` option I was preparing and as suggested by @markus :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Month,Alpha) %>% 
  summarise(N=n()) %>% 
  spread(Month,N,fill=0)#can use Alpha instead of Month
 Alpha April   Feb   Jan March
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     0     2     2
2 B         0     1     1     0
```

Comment: Thankyou. Did not think of it, very elegant.

Comment: Building off the above you can use:

`freq_table <- as.tibble(table(df)) %>% 
  spread(Alpha, n)`